# File Transfer to Synology DS414 Painfully slow

Tags: networking, windows-10, nas, synology-diskstation

We have a Synology DS414 it has 4 x 4TB Drives in Raid 5 for a total capacity of 10.9Tb

We used to have a single volume with an iSCSI LUN and mounted on to a server then mapped to everyone as mapped drive, transfer speeds were quick as it should be, but we recently switched from using iSCSI to Shared Folder so we can use "Recycle bin" functionality.

We started noticing that it is now talking too long to transfer files less than 10gb of data on our gigabit network speed.

Before we could transfer 10gb in less than 10 minutes, now its taking a lot of time, we left it running for hours and it was still not more than 10% done.

Below is our test method
Source: A:\U_A\U_W << This is a mapped drive on our File Server
Destination: O:\U_O\Test << This is a mapped drive to Synology NAS
[image: Slow Copy Speed] << Shows about 19 hours after its done calculating.

Source: A:\U_A\U_W << This is a mapped drive on our File Server
Destination: C:\U_B\Test << this is a folder on the local computer
[image: Fast Copy Speed] << Copy completes in less than 10 minutes.

Source: C:\U_B\Test  << this is a folder on the local computer
Destination: O:\U_O\Test << This is a mapped drive to Synology NAS
[image: A bit faster but still not as quick for some reason]

Also browsing directories etc on O:\ is generally slow as well
When We open explorer it takes a few seconds for the O:\ drive to appear
[image: Takes 3 - 5 seconds for O drive to appear]

here are some screenshots
[image: Volume]
[image: Storage Pool]
[image: SMB Advanced Settings]
All other file transfer types are disabled, only SMB has been left as enabled, i've tried to mess with the settings above but nothing has helped. I've tried SMB1, SMB2, SMB2 with Large MTU, SMB3 as well none of that works.

NAS Shows 1Gigabit network
[image: 1000MBPS]

Also i know someone here will ask me, so let me tell you preemptively, I've tried TeraCopy :)
Oh and all clients are Windows 10 and all servers are Windows Server 2019, All devices are connected to the same switch.

Comment: Something i missed mentioning above, the NAS is configured with Domain Authentication

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why is DHCP off? 2) Have you tried to enable SMB2 Lease? Both, once turned on, should speed discovery up, hence shorten the calculation time.

Comment: DHCP on the NAS? we have a DHCP server on the network its our DC, I haven't tried SMB2 Lease yet will test it shortly.

Comment: It may sound strange, but yes, enabling DHCP on a NAS can speed things up, if only to separate requests and make packet analysis and transfer more fluid, especially if multiple clients request access to, or demand download of, the same files at the same time. SMB2 lease would create a hierarchy in the requests (small files first, bigger files later), again that would render transfer and access more fluid.

Comment: Ok I think this "enabling DHCP" is just an April Fools Joke? but just in case it isn't I've tried it, and didn't work.

Comment: Judging by the capacity of your drives, I've assumed (wrongly?) that they were regular HDDs and not SSDs, but there are two things you should consider/check: 1) For each drive, if you check their Properties in the Hardware tab, then in the Strategies tab, what does it say in terms of deletion strategy and write cache strategy? 2) Is there a reason why your 10TB drives are formatted in ext4? While you still were using iSCSI, file systems didn't matter much, but here, without the proper thrid-party software to act as a go-between, copying files onto your hard drives is bound to be painful.

Comment: Also, large MTU is nagging me. Can you set a value manually?

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find the exact info you were asking for, but yeah for the volume the Write Cache is enabled, and data scrubbing has never been performed. I am not sure as to why it's EXT4 that was the only option available at the time of creating the volume. I am deleting data off the share and recreating the RAID array in a hope that I get a better file system format, what if there isn't any other option, what would be the recommended file system here?

Comment: Well, since you're going to access those drives from a network of PCs running Windows, I'd say the best file system would be NTFS. Others may want to pitch in on this, but Linux and macOS both recognize NTFS, and can read-write on such file system partitions without too much trouble, whereas Windows has issues with the ext file system family, always has. For the rest, I don't see anything untoward here. Changing the file system on those drives might solve your issue. Remember: you went from a TCP/IP, all-compatible solution to one hinging around Microsoft technology. This could explain that.

Comment: Synology only supports EXT4 or BTRFS -  source https://mariushosting.com/synology-which-file-system-to-use/

Comment: Then maybe you'd be better-off with BTRFS, because even though Windows doesn't support it out-of-the-box, there's an open-source driver that will let you access your NAS drives and read-write with ease (here: https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs). Your transfer rates will probably return to normal after that. You may have to restart your NAS and workstations after install, though.

Comment: Also, did you check if you could manually set the MTU values on the NAS admin page? Large MTU and SMB2 aren't a great combination.

Comment: Actually scratch that BTRFS is not supported on the model i have, it can only do EXT4

Comment: Then you'll have to rely on this program (freeware; here: http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=16) that does add support for read-write ext3-4 drives on Windows, but BTRFS would have been a better choice for storage. Too bad. You'll have to deploy that program on all your workstations, reboot them and make sure the service runs on startup (delayed if need be), because it takes a while to load on a running OS. Reboot the NAS too, for good measure. EDIT: how 'bout them MTUs...?

Comment: Yeah we are not going to do that, we'll discard it and use an old HP Micro server we has as NAS instead in the next few months, for now i've undone my changes, recreated the iSCSI connection and copying back our data to it, not sure why an iSCSI connection works fine on the same EXT4 partition. Anyways i guess i'll mark yours as answer? even though there isn't technically any correct answer here.

Comment: No, don't worry about the answer, it wasn't one to begin with, more of a lenghty troubleshooting. As for iSCSI working better, it's based on TCP/IP protocol, which is universally supported by all operating systems and file systems, as opposed to what you were trying to implement, which is based on Microsoft proprietary technology.